# sed one liner to delete replace and merge

Tags: linux, sed

I have file where i have control character are appearing at the end of the line and there are also blank lines in between the lines in file, i want both to be removed and the merge every two line into one.

I want to do it as a one liner sed which i'm doing into pieces.

**My file.**

test.log

```
d62150:fxn3008_d62150 - ^M
809MB 668MB 271MB

d62150:fxn4008_d62150 6227MB ^M

9465MB 9778MB 0MB
```

**My way of doing:**

```
$ sed -r 's/\r//g;s/-/0/g;s/([0-9]+)MB/\1/g' test.log|sed '/^$/d' |sed "N;s/\n/ /"
```

**OUTPUT:**

```
d62150:fxn3008_p62150 0   809 668 271
d62150:fxn4008_p62150 6227   9465 9778 0
```

**SED Version:** `sed (GNU sed) 4.2.2`

Comment: why not just `sed '/^$/d; /\r$/{N;s/\r\n//}'`?

Comment: it doesn't work they way its needed however it neither removes the  `control char ^M` and beside that also removes the very first char of the line like `d62150` it change that to `d62150`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe this might be what you are after:

```
sed '/^$/d;:a;/\r\n*$/{N;ba};s/\r\n*//;s/MB//g;s/-/0/g' file
```

The idea is the following:

0. read a line in the pattern-space
1. **`/^$/d`**: if the line is empty, delete it and restart the cycle
2. **`:a;/\r\n*$/{N;ba};`**: if the pattern space ends with `CR` followed by one or more `LF`, read the next line, append an `LF` and the line to the pattern-space. Keep on doing that until the pattern space ends with something else.
3. **`s/\r\n*//`:** Delete all `CRLF*` sequences.
4. **`s/MB//g;s/-/0/g`** : perform final substitutions.