# How to combine multilpe sed commands into one

Tags: linux, sed

I am unable to do the both replace and delete action into one go while using `sed` hence using multiple occurrence of the sed.

**Raw datafile**

```
d62150 fxn3008_d62150 - ^M
809MB 668MB 271MB

d62150 fxn4008_d62150_bl 6227MB ^M

9465MB 9778MB 0MB
d62150 fxn3008_d62150 - ^M
809MB 668MB 271MB

d62150 fxn4008_d62150_bl 6227MB ^M

9465MB 9778MB 0MB
d62150 fxn3008_d62150 - ^M
809MB 668MB 271MB

d62150 fxn4008_d62150_bl 6227MB ^M

9465MB 9778MB 0MB
d62150 fxn3008_d62150 - ^M
809MB 668MB 271MB

d62150 fxn4008_d62150_bl 6227MB ^M

9465MB 9778MB 0MB
d62150 fxn3008_d62150 - ^M
809MB 668MB 271MB

d62150 fxn4008_d62150_bl 6227MB ^M

9465MB 9778MB 0MB
d62150 fxn3008_d62150 - ^M
809MB 668MB 271MB

d62150 fxn4008_d62150_bl 6227MB ^M

9465MB 9778MB 0MB
```

**The current Solution i am using is :**

```
sed -i -e 's/\r//g; s/-/0/g; s/MB//g'  log1
sed '/^[[:space:]]*$/d' "$datafile.log1"| paste -d " " - - > log2
awk '{$1=$1}1' OFS="," "$datafile.log2" > log
```

**Test1 out** this will remove the control chars and `MB` while replace the `-` to `0` s desired.

```
$ sed -e 's/\r//g; s/-/0/g; s/MB//g' test22.log
d62150 fxn3008_d62150 0
809 668 271

d62150 fxn4008_d62150_bl 6227

9465 9778 0
d62150 fxn3008_d62150 0
809 668 271

d62150 fxn4008_d62150_bl 6227

9465 9778 0
d62150 fxn3008_d62150 0
809 668 271

d62150 fxn4008_d62150_bl 6227

9465 9778 0
d62150 fxn3008_d62150 0
809 668 271

d62150 fxn4008_d62150_bl 6227

9465 9778 0
d62150 fxn3008_d62150 0
809 668 271

d62150 fxn4008_d62150_bl 6227

9465 9778 0
d62150 fxn3008_d62150 0
809 668 271

d62150 fxn4008_d62150_bl 6227

9465 9778 0
```

**Test2 out**  However i see the another way of working like below which is mupltiple pipe sequences and `paste` command for joining lines and subsequently awk for making it comma separated fields.

```
$ sed -e 's/\r//g; s/-/0/g; s/MB//g' test22.log | sed '/^$/d' |  paste -d " " - -|awk '{$1=$1}1' OFS=","
d62150,fxn3008_d62150,0,809,668,271
d62150,fxn4008_d62150_bl,6227,9465,9778,0
d62150,fxn3008_d62150,0,809,668,271
d62150,fxn4008_d62150_bl,6227,9465,9778,0
d62150,fxn3008_d62150,0,809,668,271
d62150,fxn4008_d62150_bl,6227,9465,9778,0
d62150,fxn3008_d62150,0,809,668,271
d62150,fxn4008_d62150_bl,6227,9465,9778,0
d62150,fxn3008_d62150,0,809,668,271
d62150,fxn4008_d62150_bl,6227,9465,9778,0
d62150,fxn3008_d62150,0,809,668,271
d62150,fxn4008_d62150_bl,6227,9465,9778,0
```

Please help make is easier or one liner.

Comment: This is very closely related to https://stackoverflow.com/q/73105862/8344060

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You never need sed when you're using awk. Using any awk:

```
awk '
    BEGIN { OFS="," }
    !NF { next }          # Discard all empty lines
    (++c) % 2 {           # Select odd-numbered of remaining lines
        prev = $0         # Just save the line in a variable.
        next
    }
    {                     # This is an even numbered non-empty line
        $0 = prev " " $0  # Attach the previous line to the front of it
        gsub(/-/,0)
        gsub(/\r|MB/,"")
        $1 = $1           # Force replacement of all FS with OFS
        print
    }
' file
```

Comment: @ Ed, This is mot working as per desired in my post's result `Test2 out` , if you see the first line of output it not translating `-` into `0` and adding it one line further, Secondly i want this to be used inside the Shell Script itself so, i can not use  it as a `test.awk`.

Comment: I missed that you wanted `-` to become `0`, fixed that now. Any awk script can be executed as `awk 'script' input` rather than `awk -f scriptFile input`, I changed that for you now. As for "adding it one line further" - I can't imagine what you're seeing with that.

Comment: Hi Ed, Can we make it in a single line like `awk 'BEGIN { OFS="," } !NF { next } (++c) % 2 { prev = $0 next } { $0 = prev " " $0 gsub(/-/,0) gsub(/\r|MB/,"") $1 = $1 print }' test22.log` i tried but did not worked. Could you please explain the first part of code little bit that will hlep me and many more learners like me.

Comment: I added comments to the non-obvious lines. To cram it all onto 1 line discard the comments, add `;` to the end of every line that doesn't end with `{`, then remove the newlines.

Answer (score 1):

This might work for you (GNU sed):

```
sed '/^\s*$/d;:a;N;s/\n\s*$//;ta;y/- /0,/;s/\n\|\r\|MB//g' file
```

Delete any empty lines.

Once a non-empty line is established, delete any appended empty lines until another non-empty line is appended.

Translate `-` to `0` and   to `,`.

Remove any `\n`, `\r` and `MB`.

Comment: Hi potong, this does not provide the desired output.

Comment: @kulfi I did say `might` perhaps you could provide the expected result from the raw data?

Comment: expected data is under `Test2 out` in the post.

Comment: @kulfi perhaps try it again - my test is [here](https://ideone.com/xzXu6c).